# Get property from map Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How canI get a property from map and display it in a table with Angular? When I display I get [object Object]. If use property.first I don't get nothing.

```
//model

export interface UserModel { 
       room: Map<number,number> 
}


//service

export class UserService {
  user: UserModel;

  newUser: UserModel = {
    room: new Map<number,number>(),
....}}


//html
 <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of $users | async">
        <td>{{user.room}}</td> // user.room.first???
      </tr>
      
 </tbody>
```

Help me, please!

Comment: can u console log $users and share what are there ?

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of ***ngFor** is wrong here.
If you want to use *ngFor it is basically for iterating the array.
So you need to use an **array**, you cannot use Map in *ngFor.

And if your data type is Map you have to convert it in the array.

Please provide the end result that you want if you want more detailed solution in this question.

As per my understanding you want to print the value mapped with the keys in the table.

So you need to convert the keys of map into an array.
For achieving this please use:

```
this.keys = Object.keys(this.user)
```

Add this line in your .ts file and now add the following code in html.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let keyof keys| async">
    <td>{{user[key]}}</td> // user.room.first???
  </tr>
```

I hope this is your requirement. and you can get this done.

Answer (score 0):

To access map in angular template you should convert it to array or object.

```
getArray(map){
  return Array.from(map.keys());
}
```

Then access it from angular template.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let element of getArray(map)">
     <!-- element[0] is key && element[1] is value -->
    <td>{{element[0] - element[1]}}</td>
  </tr>
```

You can optimize it by store it in variable like below.

```
public mapArray;
public map;

constructor() {
  this.map = new Map();
  this.mapArray = [];
}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.doSomeThing();
  this.convertMapToArray();
}

private doSomeThing(){
  this.map.set('my_key_1', 'my_value_1');
  this.map.set('my_key_2', 'my_value_2');
}

private convertMapToArray(){
  this.mapArray = Array.from(this.map.keys());
}
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of mapArray">
  <!-- element[0] is key && element[1] is value -->
  <td>{{element[0] - element[1]}}</td>
</tr>
```